# picocom - how to read hex bytes

Tags: serial-port

I use picocom to read a serial port. I try to display hex bytes this way ([man](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch-backports/picocom/picocom.1.en.html)):

```
picocom --imap ???hex -b 19200 /dev/ttyS0
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

from `picocom` manual page:

```
--imap <map> (input mappings)
<map> is a comma-separated list of one or more of ...
```

```
picocom --imap spchex,tabhex,crhex,lfhex,nrmhex,8bithex -b 19200 /dev/ttyS0
```

Answer (score 1):

did you actually wrote '???hex'? if so, that's exactly why it did not work.

However, the most logical answer is that you are referring to the many mapping options that exist with picocom. Your line is fine as it is. What I think is happening is that your version of picocom is too old to have those features available.

For example, I have v1.7 on a raspberry pi and it doesnt work with those options either, however using v3.1, which is the latest at the moment, works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `???` isn't meant literal. The sentence `The "to hex" mappings (???hex) replace the respective characters with their hexadecimal representation (in square brackets), like this:` in the man page refers to

```
       • spchex (map special chars (< 0x20 || 0x7f), excl.  CR, LF, and TAB to hex)

       • tabhex (map TAB to hex)

       • crhex (map CR to hex)

       • lfhex (map LF to hex)

       • 8bithex (map chars with 8th-bit set to hex)

       • nrmhex (map normal ascii chars (0x20 <= c < 0x7f) to hex)
```

I think what you want to runs is

```bsh
picocom --imap 8bithex -b 19200 /dev/ttyS0
```